# Arrow to side of commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following code in a beamer doc:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=small, row sep=small]
        \&  \arrow[dl,dash] d \arrow [dr,dash]  \&  \&  \text{\footnotesize finer} \\
    \tau_a  \arrow [dr,dash]    \&  \&  \arrow[dl,dash] \tau_b  \& \\
    \& \chi \& \& \text{\footnotesize coarser} \arrow[uuu]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

The idea is that there should be an arrow on the side of the diagram connecting "coarser" to "finer"; however, the arrow does not go up three rows as instructed, but seems instead to end one row up, one to the left.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your levels count is wrong: replace `\arrow[uuu]` with`\arrow[uu]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had one `u` too much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=small, row sep=small]
        \&  \arrow[dl,dash] d \arrow [dr,dash]  \&  \&  \text{\footnotesize finer} \\
    \tau_a  \arrow [dr,dash]    \&  \&  \arrow[dl,dash] \tau_b  \& \\
    \& \chi \& \& \text{\footnotesize coarser} \arrow[uu]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]